# Keras prediction in Tornado API between version 2.2.5 and 2.3.1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tornado

I have the keras sequential model built in keras version 2.2.5 and tensorflow 1.14.0 in python 3.7.4.
For the prediction to work in Tornado API, I use graph initialization as below, it works perfectly fine

```
global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()        
with graph.as_default():
    prediction = model.predict_proba(X)
```

If I upgrade keras == 2.3.1, I get following error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Tensor dense_1_input:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph
```

May I know how to fix in the new version

Comment: No solution for this yet???????????????????